# vb.net form handling event from another form

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

In vb.net 2019, I have a form - 'form1' - that displays 'form2' (form2.Show()). form1 has the Systems.IO.Ports.SerialPort component added to it. How would I code form2 to 'handle' a serial port data receive event on form1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Calling function from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208020/c-sharp-calling-function-from-another-form)

Comment: Use 3 forms . One main create instace objects form1 and form2 from class Form. You need public method to make call...Main class instance will help you ...

Comment: Form2 can create a delegate for the event handling method using AddressOf and then Form1 can retrieve that like any other object. Form1 can then register that event hander with the SerialPort using AddHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Why not handle the event on Form1 where the control exists?

For example:

```
   Sub SerialPortDataReceiveEvent(DataReceiveObject)

      Form2.SomeProperty = DataReceiveObject.WantedProperty

   End Sub
```